# Old Sphinx 0.99 on Debian 11?

Tags: debian, sphinxsearch, debian-bullseye, sphinx

I plan to move several websites that use **Sphinx 0.99** including its old PHP API to a new Server running *Debian 10 or 11* and wonder if it would even work to get this old Sphinx version running.

To adjust the old PHP API for PHP 8 I think I could do but no idea if it will work to install Sphinx 0.99 on a new Debian Version. My old server is running Debian 8 Jessie (upgraded from Debian 6 Squeeze a few years ago without too many troubles) and everything still works perfectly fine but I have such feeling that after more than 10 years it's time to move to a new server. Is it even possible to install and run the old Sphinx version on a new Debian system or could I expect problems?

I doubt the new Sphinx is compatible in any way to how it worked at that time (setting up index files, pulling ids from search-client -> fetch from db), please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you!

Comment: what is the exact business related question in here?

Comment: @djdomi My question is if anyone else has already made experience with installing and old Sphinx version on a new Debian system or knows if installation could work.